# how to exclude footer element content from body using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a html page for an example like below

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div>test1</div><footer><div>test2</div></footer></body></html>
```

I have written xslt 1.0 to transform and extract the title and body content, but my requirement is to ignore footer content alone and consider all other element values inside body content. How to achieve this ?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <document >
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="html/head" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body" />
</document>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="html/head">
<content name="title">
<xsl:value-of select="title" />
</content>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="html/body">
<content name="snippet">
<xsl:value-of select="viv:replace(viv:replace(.,'&lt;[^>]*>',' ', 'gi'),'&amp;nbsp;','','gi')"/>
</content>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show the output you are expecting in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tim, I expect the out as <document><title>test</title><snippet>test1</snippet></document>. So for me I just need content of all divs, anchor, lists, etc elements, but want to exclude the content from "footer" element.

Answer (score 0):

Q: how to exclude footer element content from body using xslt 1.0

If this is really your question this should be answered hundred times.
Stat with an **identity transform** and have empty templates for elements to ignore.

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="body/footer"/>
```

Looking to your xlst let us assume there a some **strange_other_things** requested.

Do strange_other_things for the body without footer put the result form identity transfer into a variable.

```
<xsl:template match="body" mode="strange_other_things">
  <xsl:variable name="body" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- use $body but I'm out here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Further guess: With `viv:replace(.,'&lt;[^>]*>',' ', 'gi')` you try to remove xml element names. This will not work because `.` is used in a text context an will only return all text inside the current node.

So if I'm right the question is a lite deceptive.

Comment: as I am trying to fetch all the text inside body element except footer element texts, so with "." I am unable to achieve the requirement. How can I get the solution by using apply templates.

Comment: Use `$body` instead of `.`  in a text context. This should be all text inside of body without footer. But text her mean also without element and attributes.